# Difference in different way of defining string in c++ and passing these as parameter in function

Tags: c++, string

I know these problem which I will be telling you guys,may be very easy but I am really getting trouble while defining string in c++.Earlier I was coding in C language.Where for string I used char array to store string.
Now In c++ there are several ways for defining the string and initialization

For example:

```
1. char str[30];

2.string str="stackoverflow"; 

3.char *str="stackoverflow";
   may be many more..
```

I also googled but didn't get satisfactory answers.

QUESTIONS 1: Are these definitions of string (which i didn't include ) are same or different ?If yes then how?

QUESTION 2: I have also problem while passing string as function parameter.Are ways of passing string as parameter same in all definitions? If not,Please mention ways too.

QUESTION 3: We know that string terminates with a special character '\0'.What if I defined arr[4] and storing value "vinod" or arr[40] and storing value "vinod"? What about extra memory in second case?Although I haven't tried using program .

Comment: This looks too much like a disguised homework question for anythng other than DCV.

Comment: 'I also googled but didn't get satisfactory answers.' - no-effort homework flag.

Comment: Googling 'string types in C++' gives: 'About 9,040,000 results'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed three declarations

```
1.char str[30];

2.string str="stackoverflow"; 

3.char *str="stackoverflow"; may be many more..
```

The first one declares a character array of 30 characters.

The second one declares an object of class `std::string` and initializes it with string literal "stackoverflow".

And the third one declares a pointer to char that initialized by the address of the first character of string literal "stackoverflow".

In C++ the last declaration is incorrect because in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. It would be correctly to write

```
3.const char *str="stackoverflow"; may be many more..
```

So you declared three distinct objects of different types.

Class std::string has a constructor that allows implicitly to convert a pointer to char to an object of type std::string.

So if you have a function with a parameter of type `std::string` as for example

```
void f( std::string s );
```

then you may pass any of the declared objects above that is

1.

```
char str[30] = "stackoverflow";

f( str );
```

2.

```
std::string str = "stackoverflow"; 

f( str );
```

3.

```
const char *str = "stackoverflow";

f( str );
```

In all three cases the function will deal within itself with an object of type `std::string`.

Comment: In first 6th line it should be string literal instead of character literal isn't?

Comment: Different words, same meaning.

Comment: I don't think that character and string literal are same.

Comment: @Bam They aren't, but he meant string literal.

Comment: @Bam It was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Different types of strings:**

```
char str[30];
```

This creates a modifiable array of 30 chars. It can be used to hold a string but can also be used to hold raw data. It's common for this kind of array to be used as a byte buffer since char is exactly one byte in size.

```
string str="stackoverflow";
```

This will create a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) object passing the string literal "stackoverflow" into it's constructor. std::string will take a copy of this string literal and place it inside an internal modifiable array. std::string is much more powerful than using a plain char array because of all the in-built functionality that comes with it.

```
char *str="stackoverflow"
```

This creates a char pointer to a read-only location in memory where the string literal "stackoverflow" lives. This is NOT modifiable and trying to modify it causes undefined behaviour:

```
char *str="stackoverflow"
str[3] = 'h'; // undefined behaviour
```

**Different ways of passing them as parameters:**

As for passing these as parameters then it truly depends on what your goals are. The first type can be passed like so:

```
void foo(char str[]);
void foo(char* str); // this is valid because arrays decay into pointers.

void foo(const char str[]); // prevents function from modifying the contents of the array.
void foo(const char* str); // same as above.
void foo(const char* const str); // prevents function from modifying contents of the array and what str points to.
```

The second type can be passed by value or by reference. If you purposefully want to pass a copy of your std::string then you can pass by value. If you want to pass your std::string and not a copy then you pass by reference. If you don't want to pass by reference for performance reasons (to avoid a costly copy) and you don't want the function to modify your string then you can pass by const reference.

```
void foo(std::string str); // pass by value. A copy is passed into here.
void foo(std::string& str); // pass by reference.
void foo(const std::string& str); // avoid the copy but prevent this function from modifying your string.
```

The last type should be passed as const since it should not be modified.

```
void foo(const char* str);
void foo(const char str[]); // this is valid because arrays decay into pointers.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str="stackoverflow";
```

Assuming you mean `std::string`, this creates a string literal "stackoverflow" of type `const char[]` and then invokes the `std::string(const char*)` constructor to create an `std::string` object that holds "stackoverflow".

```
char *str="stackoverflow";
```

Because a string literal is of type `const char[]`, assigning a `char*` to it is deprecated and since C++14 illegal, however most compilers still accept it.
It creates a string literal "stackoverflow" on the stack and assigns the address of the first character 's' to the pointer `str`.

> I have also problem while passing string as function parameter.Are ways of passing string as parameter same in all definitions? If not,Please mention ways too.

In C++ you usually just want to pass a `std::string` to a function to avoid breaking stuff. If you want to avoid copying the `std::string` object, consider passing `const std::string&`.

> We know that string terminates with a special character '\0'.What if I defined arr[4] and storing value "vinod" or arr[40] and storing value "vinod"? What about extra memory in second case?

In the first example you're string to store a string literal thats too big for the array to hold, causing buffer overflow.

For `arr[40]`, your array is big enough and it'll gladly accept the string literal and store it starting from index 0. The remaining space that isn't needed is still used up.